# Why does two main functions in a single Python script work?

Tags: python

I was trying to do silly things in Python and tried the silliest of the things (see below) to see how Python reacts. To my surprise it executed perfectly. But I do not understand why.

How does Python know which `foo` to execute? Why does it not execute the same `foo` twice?

```
def main():
    foo()

def foo():
    print('this is foo 1.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

def main():
    foo()

def foo():
    print('this is foo 2.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How do you know it executed perfectly?

Comment: Because the output from the program comes out to be as it was desired. Also because i do not see any warnings as well. @quamrana

Comment: Yes, of course, but what is your desired output?

Comment: If this was two different scripts the desired out will be as below

"this is foo 1."
"this is foo 2."

and i get the same result even when they are in the same script.

Comment: Just remember that python executes code from top to bottom. When python encounters a `def function()` line, it generates code from the body of the function and does the equivalent of `function = <reference to generated code>`. That is, an assignment. This happens four times in your script, but after the first two you execute `main()` and then at the end you execute `main()` again.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: _How does Python know which foo to execute?_ There is only one foo.  The second one replaced the first one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The interpreter does these things, in the order they appear in the file:

1. Defines `main` as your first definition of that function.
2. Defines `foo` as your first definition of that function.
3. Because `__name__` is `__main__`: executes the function (currently defined as `main`) which calls the function currently defined as `foo`.
4. Redefines `main` as your second definition of that function. (Albeit that's no different from the first definition.)
5. Redefines `foo` as your second definition of that function.
6. Because `__name__` is `__main__`: executes the function (currently defined as `main`) which calls the function currently defined as `foo`, which by now is your second `foo`.

You might be assuming that the interpreter somehow does a "first pass" and processes all function definitions, and only then executes the code under `if __name__ == '__main__'`.  But that's not how it works. The steps are executed in order, like they would be if you ran:

```
x = 5
y = 7
print(x+y)
x = 6
y = 10
print(x+y)
```

For similar reasons, this code would **not** work:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   foo()

def foo():
   print(2)
```

because `foo` is undefined at the point it is referenced.

Comment: i knew about the part of redefining variables but even the function can be redefined that's like not how i imagined it. Good to know it can be done for the functions as well.

Comment: Cool, I had in mind that people wouldn't find my example with the `x` and `y` mysterious or surprising, so that's the starting point for understanding how it works with functions.

Answer (score 7):

Python executes statements from top to bottom as they appear in the input file.

So first it defines two functions `main` and `foo` and then calls `main`, leading to the output from `foo`, "this is foo 1".

Then it defines two other functions which happen to be also named `main` and `foo`, these names now refer to the new functions and the first two functions are no longer accessible by these names. You could also say that the new functions *override* the old functions or that they are *redefined*.

Then it calls `main` (which now refers to the new function) which leads to the output of the new function `foo`, "this is foo 2".

Also note that the function name `main` has no special meaning in Python.

Answer (score 0):

When `main` is called the first time, foo is the function that prints "This is foo 1.". When `main` is called the second time, foo is the function that prints "This is foo 2." Therefore, the first time, "This is foo 1." is the output, and the second time, "This is foo 2." is the output.

Answer (score -1):

Python is in interpretted language so it executes each line as it encounters it.

Which means if you ran this on the python shell or as a script your output would be determined by whatever is encountered first foo() - foo1, and then the newer value of the function foo() - foo2

Output:

> this is foo 1.

> this is foo 2.